# Could not GET '*/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden while publishing to AWS CodeArtifact

Tags: gradle, maven-publish, aws-codeartifact

I have a maven repo set up in AWS CodeArtifact. I am using `maven-publish` plugin with Gradle to publish the artifacts. However, gradle exits with the following error -

```
Could not GET 'https://.../maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the AWS Role/User which is being used to authenticate to AWS CodeArtifact does not have the following permissions on the forbidden resource -

```
"codeartifact:Get*",
"codeartifact:Describe*",
"codeartifact:List*",
"codeartifact:ReadFromRepository"
```